# Javascript Invalid Quantifier using search

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript's `.search()` function and I have this code:

```
var temp_cc_number = "4111 1111 1111 1111";
var checker = "****";
alert(temp_cc_number.search(checker));
```

I'm getting this error:

```
"Invalid quantifier"
```

What do you think this is? Any help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` is a *zero or more* quantifier, therefore if you're trying to match literal `*` you need to escape it with the `\`. Or maybe a slightly better way: `search(/\*{4}/)`. The `{4}` denotes a match count, in this case it matches the `\*` 4 times. You can also specify minimum and maximum ranges `{M:N}`, `M` being the minimum and `N` the maximum.

Comment: umm, what do you mean escape? \***\ ? Kindly show me a code please.

Thanks!

Comment: `\*\*\*\*`. Or `\*{4}`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm tyring to search a string if it has a ****